# python: создать класс с параметром

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, абстрактная-фабрика

подскажите, можно ли в питоне сделать следующее:

создать некоторую функцию, которая в зависимости от параметра будет выдавать классы (некоторая фабрика), например:

```
def factory(v):
    if v == 0:
        return Class0
    elif v == 1:
        return Class1
    else:
        return ClassCustom
```

чтобы уже в дальнейшем использовать классы обычным способом

```
Class = factory(1)
value = Class('abc')
```

**Так вот вопрос**

можно ли создать класс, которому при создании указать некоторый параметр, который потом будут получать все экземпляры класса, т.е. что-то типа

```
else:
    return ClassCustom(v)
```

и тогда

```
ClassOne = factory(1000)
ClassTwo = factory(2000)

co = ClassOne('abc')
ct = ClassTwo('xyz')
```

При этом фактически ClassOne и ClassTwo - это все один класс ClassCustom, но внутри каждого сидит свое значение переменной (к примеру) - 1000 и 2000 соответственно и у соответствующих экземпляров будет тоже самое -

```
co.v - 1000
ct.v - 2000
```

Как вариант вижу решение в виде лямбда оболочки

```
else:
    return lambda arg: ClassCustom(v, arg)
```

Но не является ли это костылем, может можно сделать как-то более правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставленную вами задачу можно выполнить с помощью type. Это метакласс. Код может выглядеть вот так:

```
def some_func(self):
    return self.x
def return_class():
    return type("ClassName", (), {"x":5,"func":some_func})
my_class= return_class()
obj = my_class()
print(obj.x, obj.func(), type(obj))
```

Вывод

```
5 5 <class '__main__.ClassName'>
```

type принимает три аргумента на вход, название класса, tuple, где перечисляются наследники ( в примере он пуст), и словарь методов и атрибутов у будущего класса. При одном аргументе type возвращает тип переданного ей объекта.

Comment: Если что-то не понятно, можете спрашивать. Постараюсь ответить.